# How to make jQuery validation rule - enter value that is not in array, basically to make values unique?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a web application in which I have used jQuery validation engine for the client side validations.
This application maintains the record for which user have to enter some ID basically a number.
I maintain an array of all the serial number that users enter.

Now I want a validation on the form, that the value of ID enter by user should be already entered, means should not be in array.

egs: ids = {1,2,3,6,8}, Now next value of ID cannot be the values from the array ids. I want to write such rule in validation engine.

```
var validator = $("#formId").validate({ 
        rules: { 
            uniqueId: <Rule to write here ???>, 
        }, 
        messages: { 
            uniqueId: "Entered ID already exists", 

        }, 
    });
```

Kindly help me out. **Also if anyone has some link of tutorials or something from where I can learn all the possible validation rule implementations... that would be great**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never worked with jQuery validation, but this should get you started.
First create the validation function

```
function validateID(value, element) {
    if(ids.indexOf(value) > -1) {
        //value does exist in ids
    }
    else {
       //value does not exist in ids
       //(maybe add it to ids?)
    }
}
```

Then add it to the jquery validation rules:

```
$.validator.addMethod("idRule", validateID, "message");
```

And create a rule:

```
var validator = $("#formId").validate({ 
    rules: { 
        uniqueId: { 
            idRule: true
        } 
    }, 
    messages: { 
        uniqueId: "Entered ID already exists", 

    }, 
});
```

Here's a [blog post](http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2008/10/starting-with-jquery-how-to-write.html) where I found much of this information, you may find it useful too

Comment: This is just a normat javascript validation.. I want a rule that I can put into validation engine on jQuery.. correct me If I am wrong..

Comment: You are correct, I misunderstood the question. I have edited my answer